# iOS: scrollsToTop doesn't work when I switch views

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

I'm switching controllers via my navigation controller. When my app first loads the Appointment screen will scrollsToTop just fine. Once I switch controllers to Customers with

```
CustomerViewController *customers = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CustomerViewController"];
[self.navController.view removeFromSuperview];
self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:customers];
self.navController.view.frame = self.contentView.bounds;
[self.contentView addSubview:self.navController.view];
```

it stops working. Then switching back to my Appointments controller with

```
AppointmentViewController *appointments = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AppointmentViewController"];
[self.navController.view removeFromSuperview];
self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:appointments];
self.navController.view.frame = self.contentView.bounds;
[self.contentView addSubview:self.navController.view];
```

and then clicking the status bar the Appointments no longer scrolls to top. I have `scrollsToTop` set to `YES` in all of my controllers that load so they should be scrolling to the top. Anyone know why this stops working when I switch controllers then switch back?

EDIT:

I have my `RootViewController` which is my side menu (blue menu) and my `AppointmentViewController` which is the right side view.
[image: View Controller].

The above code is in my RootViewController to determine which view should be placed on top.

Comment: Why aren't your navigation controllers set up in your storyboard?  Why are you creating them in code?

Comment: @robmayoff huh? They are in storyboard. I created a facebook style slide menu.

Comment: The code you posted says `[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:...]`.  What do you think that does?

Comment: @robmayoff And what is wrong with creating it programmatically?

Comment: If you have a reason to create it programmatically, then do so.  But what's your reason?

Comment: Do you have a reason for setting `self.navController = nil` immediately before you set `self.navController` to a newly-created object?

Comment: @robmayoff what does that have to do with this issue?

Comment: The way you've implemented this code implies that you don't really understand how your view controllers fit together.  I'm trying to figure out whether that implication is correct.  If you don't understand how they fit together, then it's likely that you're also doing things strangely, and possibly incorrectly, in other places where it would cause the behavior you're seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not removing the old `self.navController` from your `contentView`.

Comment: You keep adding subviews via `[self.contentView addSubview:self.navController.view];`, but you never call `[self.navController.view removeFromSuperview];` (which should be done before you reassign `self.navController`).

Comment: This fixed the issue. The multiple views that were set to scrollToTop were causing the issue.